# Are there any forks or alternate flavors of Ethereum that allow cross-chain swaps between two EVM-like chains?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

I’d like to run an alternative consensus protocol based on the geth client. Since geth already has a ton of consensus protocols, I was wondering if any coins on the market were able to do the following:

- On the Ethereum blockchain, ether is sent to a smart contract from account A.
- On the alternate blockchain, a coin/token is sent to the same address found in account A.  This coin/token is valid only on the other chain.

Such a mechanism would ideally be bidrectional across chains.

What might the challenges be in designing such a system? Such a mechanism could be more difficult to implement if one needed to wait for confirmations.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at https://tendermint.com? I believe it can be used to create exactly what you're requesting by replicating a blockchain/creating a side chain where you can use your own consensus mechanism however it's not production ready yet as far as I know.

Comment: Yea I have... I'm interested in using geth's POA consensus though